# Elixir opaque structure

Tags: struct, elixir

I tried using the `@opaque` attribute to create an Opaque type but dialyzer will only catch if I try to peak at the struct and will not prevent someone outside the module to do create a `%XXX{}` struct.

How can I create a `%XXX{}` struct that is only readable/writable by `XXX` module?

(what I'd like to achieve: http://sporto.github.io/elm-patterns/advanced/opaque-types.html)

Comment: This is impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: A very partial workaround is to implement the Inspect protocol for your type. Then, the users of your module won't easily see inside the type (of course, it is not a complete solution, since there is none in Elixir).